# ¿Cómo conseguir que el algoritmo pueda devolver la suma y el promedio?

Tags: java

Es una adaptación de un código tomado de:
http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com/2012/12/arraylist-en-java.html

La idea es que se lean los nombres de alumnos, se numeren y se lean las notas de los mismos en un arreglo dinámico, posteriormente, se calcule la sumatoria de los valores de las notas y el promedio.

Se trabaja con un `arraylist` anidado

```
    //crear un ArrayList bidimensional de enteros vacío
    //Realmente se crea un ArrayList de ArrayLists de enteros
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> array = new ArrayList();
```

El Sistema lee los nombres de los alumnos y los asocia a un índice
Igualmente para las notas

```
        for(i=0;i < numAlumnos;i++){
            cont = 1;
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduzca nombre del(a) alumno(a) ");
            alumno = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Alumno numero " +(i+1) +" :" + alumno);
            System.out.println("Introduzca notas (Nota max. 100 puntos) y digite un No. < 0 para acabar: ");
            System.out.print("Nota " + cont + ": ");
            nota = sc.nextInt();


           //para cada alumno se añade una nueva fila vacía
           //esto es necesario porque el arrayList se crea vacío
            array.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

            while(nota >= 0){
                array.get(i).add(nota); //en la fila i se añade un nueva nota
                cont++;
                System.out.print("Nota " + cont + ": ");
                nota = sc.nextInt(); 
                suma = suma + nota;
                System.out.println("Suma: " + suma);
                System.out.println("Media: " + suma/array.size());              
            }           
        
        
        }
       
        //Mostrar todas las notas
        System.out.println("Notas de alumnos");
        for(i=0;i < array.size();i++){                       //para cada alumno (para cada fila)
            System.out.print("Alumno " + (i+1) + ": ");
            for(j=0;j < array.get(i).size();j++){            //se recorre todas la columnas de la fila            
                System.out.print(array.get(i).get(j) + " "); //se obtiene el elemento i,j
            }
            System.out.print("Estas es la posicion de la(s) nota(s) ingresada(s): " + i +" "+ (j-1));
            System.out.println();          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Te faltó decir que lenguaje es

Comment: No entiendo que problema estás teniendo.

Comment: Gracias por atender mi requerimiento...Es lenguaje java.

Comment: Anexe el código que no trabaja en cuanto a la implementación de la suma y el promedio de notas

Comment: suma = suma + nota;
            System.out.println("Suma: " + suma);
            System.out.println("Media: " + suma/array.size());

Comment: No sé como lograr exactamente referenciar los valores de la notas para que se sumen correctamente, en un array normal se invoca el valor del índice, en arraylist y más anidado y en el contexto de este código, ¿cómo debo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

El algoritmo solución es:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayListAnidadoBidi {


    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numAlumnos;  //número de alumnos
        int i, j, nota=0, cont = 1;
        String alumno;
        int sumaFila;
        int sumaTotal = 0;

        System.out.println("Introduzca numero de alumnos a relacionar en el arreglo bidimensional: ");
        numAlumnos = sc.nextInt();
        
        //crear un ArrayList bidimensional de enteros vacío
        //Realmente se crea un ArrayList de ArrayLists de enteros
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> array = new ArrayList();                                        
       
        //Se leen las notas de cada alumno.
        
        for(i=0;i < numAlumnos;i++){
            cont = 1;
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduzca nombre del(a) alumno(a) ");
            alumno = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Alumno numero " +(i+1) +" :" + alumno);
            System.out.println("Introduzca notas (Nota max. 100 puntos) y digite un No. < 0 para acabar: ");
            System.out.print("Nota " + cont + ": ");
            nota = sc.nextInt();

           //para cada alumno se añade una nueva fila vacía
           //esto es necesario porque el arrayList se crea vacío
            array.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

            while(nota >= 0){
                array.get(i).add(nota); //en la fila i se añade un nueva nota
                cont++;
                System.out.print("Nota " + cont + ": ");
                nota = sc.nextInt();
            }                       
        }

        for(i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        sumaFila = 0;
            for(j = 0; j < array.get(i).size(); j++) {
            sumaFila += array.get(i).get(j);
            }
        sumaTotal += sumaFila;
        }
        
        //Mostrar todas las notas
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("A continuacion se presenta el resumen de la informacion ingresada: ");
        for(i=0;i < array.size();i++){                       //para cada alumno (para cada fila)
            System.out.print("Alumno " + (i+1) + ": ");
            for(j=0;j < array.get(i).size();j++){            //se recorre todas la columnas de la fila            
                System.out.print(array.get(i).get(j) + " "); //se obtiene el elemento i,j
            }
            System.out.println("/Posicion de la(s) nota(s) ingresada(s): " + i +" "+ (j-1));
            System.out.println();   
        }
        if (nota < 0){
        System.out.println("La Suma del total de notas ingresadas para todos los alumnos es: " + sumaTotal);
        System.out.println("La media de la anterior sumatoria es: "+ sumaTotal/array.size());
        }
    }
}
```

Agradezco de nuevo a quienes intentaron ayudarme, la clave está en hacer una abstracción correcta entre objetos y tipos primitivos y hacer el casting correcto para posiciones y valores conforme requerimiento.